# Управление с помощью Python программой Ansys

Tags: python, c, api, embedded

Дано:

1. наш любимый Python
2. программа Ansys
3. Ansys C API для создания пользовательских библиотек DLL
   Функции этой библиотеки могут вызваны внутри Ansys

**Вопрос:** как я могу с помощью Python C API наладить "мост" между Python и Ansys?

Хочу отправлять команды и принимать результаты(массивы, строки, скаляры)

Comment: Вы хотите встроить (embed) Питон в ANSYS? Работает ли прямой подход: [Еmbedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html)

Comment: @jfs Я пытаюсь это сделать. Если делать "прямой подход", то хотелки не получится... Видимо, стоит уточнить, что есть желание сделать  возможной работу с внутренними командами Ansys через IDE с Python, так как Ansys C API позволяет генерировать внутренние команды Ansys, а так же принимать значения массивов и скаляров. Куда стоит копать? Потоки(Tread), Сокеты?

Comment: Не понял ваш комментарий. Если вы хотите через сокеты общаться, то при чём тут C API? Определитесь, хотите ли вы создать DLL, которая загружается Ansys и использует встроенный Питон-интерпретатор для своей функциональности ИЛИ хотите ли создать модуль для Питона, который дёргает Ansys, по предоставляемому (сетевому?) интерфейсу.

Comment: @jfs Я не пробовал ни одного варианта, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Если вы не пробовали очевидные варианты (вроде приведённой ссылки), то что мешает попробовать и если не получится, то в вопросе сказать: сделал A, B, C (согласно указанной интрукции), ожидал получить X, получаю Y. Версии софта такие-то. Если не хотите сами работу выполнять, то хотя бы укажите *конкретные* требования (чтобы информацию по капле не выдавливать). Иначе самый простой способ взаимодействия: сгенерируйте входные файлы в Питоне, запустите Ansys, анализируйте результат в Питоне, повторите.

Comment: @jfs пробую пойти путём встраивания Python.